# electorn builder - не получается настроить путь к файлу .css, .js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http, ejs

Проблема возникает после сборки приложения через electorn builder. Если запускать просто через консоль всё работает.
Как я понял electorn builder не понимает путь к файлам и папке views. Пока что решение не нашёл, пробовал через path, то же не получилось. Продолжаю копать, может кто поможет? Заранее спасибо. Это лишь мои догадки.

Проблема после компиляции: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[Ссылка на GitHub на свою разработку, всё кроме самой БД](https://github.com/Suvor4eg/VacuumWork.git)

Comment: почему вы пишете сервис, используя низкоуровневый модуль `http`, а не более простые express/koa/fastify?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, да уже понял что нужно использовать exspress и уже накидал там программу, подразобрался. Плюс я собираю приложение на electron. Теперь проблема другая. При сборке возникает проблема с путями к файлу css.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл решение, записал папку views в resource через package.json

```
"extraResources": ["views"]
```

Далее в папку с основным кодом указал пути к файлам и папке:
`appp.set('views', './resources/views');` соответственно: `res.render('index.ejs');`

```
res.sendFile('style.css', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../views') });

res.sendFile('script.js', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../views') });
```